# Ошибка "No repository found at..." (android sdk14 eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

После обновления к SDK14 (Android), я сразу же получил ошибку:

> `No repository found at jar:file:/D:/Originals/Others/eclipse/plugins/net.sf.fjep.fatjar_0.0.31.jar!/.`

Я закрыл ее, конечно. Потом попробовал скомпилировать мой, рабочий до этого, проект и получил следующую ошибку:

> `your project contains error please fix them before running your application`

И еще много ошибок в консоли.

> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]
> ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]
> Android Asset Packaging Tool
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]
> Usage: [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a]
> file.{zip,jar,apk} [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    List
> contents of Zip-compatible archive.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk}
> [asset [asset ...]] [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    badging
> Print the label and icon for the app
> declared in APK. [2011-10-25 19:44:26
> - Kill_shemoded]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> resources        Print the resource
> table from the APK. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> configurations   Print the
> configurations in the APK. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    xmltree
> Print the compiled xmls in the given
> assets. [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    xmlstrings    
> Print the strings of the given
> compiled xml assets. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]  aapt
> p[ackage]
> [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M
> AndroidManifest.xml]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]         [-0
> extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g
> tolerance] [-j jarfile]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]      
> [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL]
> [--target-sdk-version VAL] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [--app-version VAL]
> [--app-version-name TEXT]
> [--custom-package VAL]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]      
> [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE]  [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]         [--utf16]
> [--auto-add-overlay]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]      
> [--max-res-version VAL]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]         [-I
> base-package [-I base-package ...]] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G
> class-list-file] [-P
> public-definitions-file]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]         [-S
> resource-sources [-S resource-sources
> ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J
> R-file-dir]  [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]         [--product
> product1,product2,...]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]      
> [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...]
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> Package the android resources.  It
> will read assets and resources that
> are [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    supplied with the -M
> -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    options control
> which files are output. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]  [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]  aapt
> r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1
> [file2 ...] [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    Delete specified
> files from Zip-compatible archive.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk}
> file1 [file2 ...] [2011-10-25 19:44:26
> - Kill_shemoded]    Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> aapt v[ersion] [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    Print program
> version. [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]  [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]  Modifiers: [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -a  print
> Android-specific data (resources,
> manifest) when listing [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -c 
> specify which configurations to
> include.  The default is all
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> configurations.  The value of the
> parameter should be a comma
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> separated list of configuration
> values.  Locales should be specified
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> as either a language or
> language-region pair.  Some examples:
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> en [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]             port,en
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> port,land,en_US [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]        If you put the
> special locale, zz_ZZ on the list, it
> will perform [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]     
> pseudolocalization on the default
> locale, modifying all of the
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> strings so you can look for strings
> that missed the [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]     
> internationalization process.  For
> example: [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]          
> port,land,zz_ZZ [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -d  one or more
> device assets to include, separated by
> commas [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -f  force overwrite
> of existing files [2011-10-25 19:44:26
> - Kill_shemoded]    -g  specify a pixel tolerance to force images to
> grayscale, default 0 [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -j 
> specify a jar or zip file containing
> classes to include [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -k  junk
> path of file(s) added [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -m  make
> package directories under location
> specified by -J [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -u  update existing
> packages (add new, replace older,
> remove deleted files) [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -v 
> verbose output [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -x  create extending
> (non-application) resource IDs
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> -z  require localization of resource attributes marked with [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> localization="suggested" [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -A 
> additional directory in which to find
> raw asset files [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -G  A file to output
> proguard options into. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    -F 
> specify the apk file to output
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> -I  add an existing package to base include set [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -J  specify where to
> output R.java resource constant
> definitions [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -M  specify full
> path to AndroidManifest.xml to include
> in zip [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -P  specify where to
> output public resource definitions
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will
> be scanned [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]        and the first
> match found (left to right) will take
> precedence. [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    -0  specifies an
> additional extension for which such
> files will not [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]        be stored
> compressed in the .apk.  An empty
> string means to not [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> compress any files at all. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --debug-mode [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]        inserts
> android:debuggable="true" in to the
> application node of the [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> manifest, making the application
> debuggable even on production devices.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --min-sdk-version [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]        inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest. 
> If the version is 7 or [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> higher, the default encoding for
> resources will be in UTF-8.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --target-sdk-version [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to
> manifest. [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    --max-res-version
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> ignores versioned resource directories
> above the given value. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]    --values
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> when used with "dump resources" also
> includes resource values. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --version-code [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]        inserts
> android:versionCode in to manifest.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --version-name [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]        inserts
> android:versionName in to manifest.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --custom-package [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]        generates R.java into a different package.
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --auto-add-overlay [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> Automatically add resources that are
> only in overlays. [2011-10-25 19:44:26
> - Kill_shemoded]    --rename-manifest-package [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> Rewrite the manifest so that its
> package name is the package name
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> given here.  Relative class names (for
> example .Foo) will be [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> changed to absolute names with the old
> package so that the code [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]        does
> not need to change. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --rename-instrumentation-target-package [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> Rewrite the manifest so that all of
> its instrumentation [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> components target the given package. 
> Useful when used in [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> conjunction with
> --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]        a package that
> has been renamed. [2011-10-25 19:44:26
> - Kill_shemoded]    --product [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> Specifies which variant to choose for
> strings that have [2011-10-25 19:44:26
> - Kill_shemoded]        product variants [2011-10-25 19:44:26 -
> Kill_shemoded]    --utf16 [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]     
> changes default encoding for resources
> to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> level is set to 7 or higher where the
> default encoding is UTF-8. [2011-10-25
> 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> --non-constant-id [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded]        Make the resources ID non constant. This is
> required to make an R java class
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> that does not contain the final value
> but is used to make reusable compiled
> [2011-10-25 19:44:26 - Kill_shemoded] 
> libraries that need to access
> resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вопроса непонятно: SDK обновлен до v14, а Android Development Tools в Эклипсе до соответствующей версии обновили? Если нет, то первым делом нужно обновить (в Эклипсе Help -> CheckUpdates).

Если вдруг не поможет, то я бы на вашем месте удалил и ADT и SDK и поставил заново.

P.S.: И скорее всего ваша проблема с [R.java id Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/46909/r-java-id-android) связана именно с этим же.

Comment: Консоль слишком велика.
Правлю вопрос с кодом ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте правый клик по проекту -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.

Comment: Ничего не происходит. ошибка осталась