# В R.java не генерируются id

Tags: android, eclipse

В R.java перестали генерироваться id. Причина неизвестна. Скрин:

[image: снимок]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая мысль, конечно: переименовать файлик в папке drawable так, чтобы название начиналось с букв. Также нельзя использовать Заглавные буквы (это я на всякий случай :) )

А раз у Вас такого файлика и нет, то в Eclipse такие действия:

1. **Project/Clean**
2. **Project/Build project**

ЕСЛИ НЕ ПОМОЖЕТ, можно создать папку Drawable и проделать тоже самое ещё раз.

p.s. я же надеюсь в папках drawable-ldpi и drawable-mdpi у Вас нет файла с названием 11 :)

**P.P.S.** Вдруг у кого-то ещё возникнет такая ситуация.
Причина оказалась в скрытом файле Thumb.db, который иногда сама создаёт Винда. Чтобы всегда видеть все файлы у Вас в папке res можно в Eclipse настроить так:

[image]

Comment: Project/Clean - сделал, после этого пропал файл R.java.

Project/Build project - результата никакого, по прежнему нету файла R.java.

Drawable тоже пробовал создать, но не помогло.

Comment: Ещё такое:
зайдите на диске в папку своего проекта. Там зайдите в папку res и там пройдитесь по всем папочкам и посмотрите на названия файлов: чтобы небыло файлов с заглавными, файлов начинающихся с цифры и файлов содержащих в названиях непонятные символы.
У меня на днях была ситуация когда тоже не создавалася R.java и выяснилось, что файл, который в Eclipse выглядел как assistent.xml в папке ресурсов (правда папка была создана с помощью импорта всего проекта в архив и увидел я это в архиве а не в workspace) вместо буквы "а" вначале названия имел закарлючку какую-то :(

Comment: Да и тут все в порядке.

Не откажусь от помощи по TeamVeawer'у может я в корни что-то не так делаю..

Answer (score 1):

Аналогичная проблема у меня была. Сделал `Clean` проекта, исчез `R.class`. Долго искал решение, не нашел. Заново пробовал клин и бьюлд. Ничего не помогало. И вот сегодня снова сделал клин, R.class появился, причину не понял. Ну это здорово, что клин клином вышибают :).

Answer (score 1):

Короче народ, тоже долго мучился, читал английские манускрипты американских друидов-шаманов, ТИПА шарящих в андроид-коде, помогло вот что:
в файле res/values/**strings.xml** есть две строчки по-умолчанию:

`<string name="app_name">Name</string>`

`<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>`

если их удалить или изменить - **R.jawa** начинает страдать фигнёй. Эти параметры связаны с **AndroidManifest.xml** и чем-то ещё (найдёте сами, так как я поспешил поделиться этой прекрасной новостью и не стал вдаваться в подробности).

Ну и да, необходимо поставить проект на АвтоБилд:
**Project** > **Build Atomatically**
После сделайте Чистку:
**Project** > **Clean...**

Answer (score 1):

А я вот тоже с бубном танцевал.
Потом взял Эклипс перезагрузил, нажал  Project > Build
И вуаля, всё сгенерилось.

Глючит иногда Эклипс. Надо его перезагружать....

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поудалять строки

```
import android.R;
```

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная проблема. Проблема, как сказал dmitriy4leex крылась в файле strings.xml. Название было start_android_lesson1 и даже IDEA ругалась на название. Убрал 1 в конце и всё заработало.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.